# Onclick doesn't call function in php echo for loop

Tags: javascript, php, function, onclick, call

I created a loop of div's as image thumbnails that can be clicked and every div gets an onclick method while the for loop but if i click on the thumbnails, it doesn't call my function test().

I don't know where the failure is.

I would be very happy for every help.

is there any solution to do this?

i am sitting since hours on that problem but without success.

Thanks a lot for helps!

```
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
 
</head>



<style>
.album-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: white;
}

.album-container > div {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border:1px solid lightgray;
}  
    .album-container > div:hover{
        opacity: 0.7;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
    }
</style>

<script> 
function test(){
    alert("HELLO");
}
</script>



<body>
<div class="container album-container">
    <?php
    $path    = 'pics/gallery';
    $files = scandir($path);
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
    foreach($files as $file){
     echo  '<div class="photo_thumb" id="'.$file.'" onclick="test()"  style="background-image:url(pics/gallery/'.$file.')"></div>';
    }    
    ?>
</div>
    

</body>
```

Comment: Have you looked at your generated page with devtools? It works fine for me..

Comment: If it doesn't call the function, then what does it call? What specifically isn't working? Inspect the rendered page in your browser to see the structure, and check for any errors in the console.

Comment: I inspected the page but it is not working. The onclick method doesnt call the javascript function